I borrowed USDC which is my token1 But I'm receiving the loan in my WETH which is my token0, how do I solve this
I have done everything from beginning and it seems to work pretty well, untill I get to the part where I receive the loan.
I received the loan successfully but the problem is that I borrowed USDC which is my token1
But I'm receiving the loan in my WETH which is my token0
hich prints logs for debugging:
function uniswapV3FlashCallback(
uint256 fee0,
uint256 fee1,
bytes calldata data
) external {
require(msg.sender == address(pool), "not authorized");
FlashCallbackData memory decoded = abi.decode(
    data,
    (FlashCallbackData)
);

console.log("Balance of token1 on contract(before paying off loan):"); 
console.log(token1.balanceOf(address(this)));
console.log("Balance of token1 on pool(before paying off loan):"); 
console.log(token1.balanceOf(address(pool)));

// Repay borrow
if (fee0 > 0) {
    token0.transferFrom(decoded.caller, address(this), fee0);
    token0.transfer(address(pool), decoded.amount0 + fee0);
}
if (fee1 > 0) {

    //Paying off the loan (back to the pool) with fee
    token1.transfer(address(pool), decoded.amount1 + fee1);
    console.log("Balance of token1 on contract (after paying off loan):"); 
    console.log(token1.balanceOf(address(this))); 
    console.log("Balance of token1 on pool (after paying off loan):"); 
    console.log(token1.balanceOf(address(pool))); 
}

// console.log("Fee0:");
// console.log(fee0);//0
console.log("Fee1:");
console.log(fee1);

}
